# submit form without page refresh - click function toggle() not working after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form which processes without page refresh, it works great, saves to db etc.

But once i have submitted the form the click function below does not toggle anymore unless i refresh the page.

```
$("#pinlink").click(function () {
        $("#pincontent").toggle();
});
```

Here is the code:

```
echo'<strong>Printer PIN:</strong>&nbsp;<a id="pinlink"><img src="images/edit.png" width="18px" height="18px" title="Edit you PIN number"></a>

<div id="results"><div>

<div id="pinnumber">'.$learner->idnumber.'<div>                 

<div id="pincontent" style="display:none;">
<form name="myform" id="myform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
<input type="text" name="idnumber" id="idnumber" placeholder="Enter your new PIN" size="20" value=""/>
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="'.$learner->id.'" />      
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"> 
</form>
<div>';


$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#pinlink").click(function () {
    $("#pincontent").toggle();
    });

    $("#myform").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            idnumber: "required",
        },
        messages: {
            idnumber: "Please enter your PIN",
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $("#pincontent").hide();
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found the error, you forgot to close the divs correctly. (at results div and  pinnumber )

It should work:

```
echo'<strong>Printer PIN:</strong>&nbsp;<a id="pinlink"><img src="images/edit.png" width="18px" height="18px" title="Edit you PIN number"></a>

<div id="results"></div>

<div id="pinnumber">'.$learner->idnumber.'</div>                 

<div id="pincontent" style="display:none;">
<form name="myform" id="myform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
<input type="text" name="idnumber" id="idnumber" placeholder="Enter your new PIN" size="20" value=""/>
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="'.$learner->id.'" />      
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"> 
</form>
<div>';


$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#pinlink").click(function () {
    $("#pincontent").toggle();
    });

    $("#myform").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            idnumber: "required",
        },
        messages: {
            idnumber: "Please enter your PIN",
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $("#pincontent").hide();
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I feel so stupid. Thank you very much, i should learn to sleep more.

Comment: Don't worry :) There is a  Hungarian proverb for it: Only that person doesn't make mistake, who doesn't work :) (It's usual , I work as a  php developer for 4 year, but sometimes I have same mistake)

Comment: Also I really recommend, to avoid to use HTML code in PHP. The place of the HTML code is the template.

Answer (score 0):

Can you upgrade to the latest version of jQuery? I am wondering whether the new on() method would work better instead of click()..?

Use:

```
$("#pinlink").on("click", function() { });
```

Or better:

```
$(document).on("click", "#pinlink", function() { });
```

This second form makes use of something called event delegation, which may help in this situation as the click handler seems to be becoming unbound after the AJAX response...

If you can't upgrade, try using the delegate() method instead:

```
$(document).delegate("click", "#pinlink", function() { });
```

Comment: hi, cant get any of your examples to work. im using <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>. They all work as described in my question But once i have submitted the form the click function still doesn't toggle unless i refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with bind?

```
 $("#pinlink").bind('click', function() {
    $("#pincontent").toggle();
    });
```

Comment: hi, cant get your example to work. It works as described in my question But once i have submitted the form the click function still doesn't toggle unless i refresh the page